# Срабатывание else в цикле for

Tags: python

Даны два множества. В условии сказано, что если в этих множествах есть общие аргументы, то надо вывести их на экран, в противном случае, вывести `EMPTY`. Не могу догадаться, почему не работает этот код. `else` срабатывает всегда. Через `True` тоже не сработало.

```
for i in list1 & list2:
    print(i)
else:
    print('EMPTY')
```

Comment: Слово else, примененное в цикле for или while, проверяет, был ли произведен выход из цикла инструкцией break, или же "естественным" образом. Блок инструкций внутри else выполнится только в том случае, если выход из цикла произошел без помощи break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и в одну строчку:

```py
print(*list1 & list2 or ["EMPTY"], sep=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто проверять, пустое ли пересечение множеств или нет. Если оно не пустое - выводить пересечение, иначе, выводить empty

```
if a & b:
    print(a & b)
else:
    print("empty")
```